# Analyzing the iPhone's moisture sensor

Tags: iphone, ipad

Every time I'm near a Genius Bar I see a lot of ENT (ear, nose, throat) microscopes peering down the headphone jack of various iPhones. I asked about it and found that the moisture sensor is down there, and if your device got wet then it turns red, and the purpose of that is that you don't have a warranty and don't get a free new device if it has mysteriously died but the cause is moisture.

I'm curious about how these things work and whether this simple examination could be subverted. I don't have a wet iPhone and I'm not looking to defraud Apple here, but I'm curious.

- The sensor must involve a chemical reaction, if it didn't show the indicator color when it dried it wouldn't be much good. What is the reaction and is it reversible? Would the required reagent be safe to drip down the headphone opening?
- Could one buy a new sensor component, open the phone and replace it?
- How about simply getting a material that looks like the sensor, opening the phone and putting it in place of the sensor - an inert sensor?
- Simplest of all, painting the sensor - if the "OK" color is white then a paint marker should do.

Again, not trying to get a free phone here. I'm curious about devices like this since I saw my first "tip-n-tell" on a shipping carton, and played with Maxim iButton temperature loggers.

Comment: While these questions are interesting, I'm not sure they're very well suited for Ask Different...

Comment: The FAQ says nothing against it. I think it's a legitimate question for AskDifferent.

Comment: I certainly think it's legitimate. I don't think these sensors are in use in any other device I own.

Comment: You say you don't want to defraud Apple, but all your questions aim to do just that. You ask of ways to reverse the chemical reaction, replace the sensor entirely with one that hasn't "gone off," a chameleon sensor, or to mask the color. None of those questions have any serious scientific merit or aid the community at large. They only serve to do exactly what you claim you have no interest in doing.

Comment: Although you may not be looking to defraud Apple, some others will be and will find this question if they search on Google, we should not promote this type of activity.

Comment: Well how far does this go - do you think pentalobe drivers (or for that matter tri-wing or torx) should be outlawed? Knowledge is interesting for its own sake. In contrast with the thermochron button and the tip-n-tell sensor these do seem like fallible devices. If I'm really a criminal and want free iPhones, simply stealing them is surely a better way. Don't do that either, readers.

Comment: I don't see a reason for this question to be downvoted. And beside, there are MANY devices containing such sensors (it make my head ache calling those snippets sensors *grr*), but Apple is famous for using them.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31110/how-can-you-find-out-if-your-iphone-ever-got-wet/31113 could interest you as well!

Comment: Thanks Max. FWIW I'm not seeing any justification for downvotes either.

Comment: Every cellphone and most laptops contain them, and have long before the iPhone came out.  This is not an Apple specific query, and I disagree that it's suitable for this site.

Comment: Change the Title from "Hacking..." to "Analyzing..." and see if you get a different reaction.

Comment: Changed. But the dog pile is already on! I'm not deleting it, those who want to play tactical voting - for obvious reasons - can take away as many points as they want. I want to know.

Comment: As I said, if you asked "how do those moisture sensors work?" I'd be cool with this question. But you didn't. You went out of your way to riffle off several questions that all deal with pullin the wool over Apple's eyes and hiding moisture damage. You don't ask if they were even a reliable indicator of water damage. You can compare this to pentalobe screws or IDE connectors all day long but none of those are used to indicate damage to hardware. Apples to oranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An inert "sensor" would be white paper.
An actually working sensor could be paper coated with cobalt(II) chloride, whose hexa hydrate (cobalt chloride "containing" water) turns light red.
If you want to tamper with the original sensor, think of water free clear coat.

Comment: Thank you. I know next to nothing about the chemistry of these sensors and this is interesting to me. I hope nobody assumes you're interested in facilitating fraud by telling me this.

Comment: @AdamEberbach Actually, I don't know what kind of water sensor Apple uses. But this reaction changes from light blue to light red. This could be what they are using. And it's one of the most common test reaction for water.

Comment: Why does this answer get downvoted?

Comment: For the same reason that people are downvoting the question...you're being judged as guilty by association.  It's unfortunate.

Comment: This is white hat hacking.

Comment: Too many people see no difference. I wonder if anyone thinks my old 2.5" to 3.5" IDE adapter for the G4 Mac mini was fraudulently depriving Apple of Mac Pro sales?